# Adding char[] to vector

Tags: c++, visual-c++

Trying to add value to `vector` :

```
std::vector<char[256] > readers;

char d[256];
strcpy(d, "AAA");
readers.push_back(d);
```

Got error:

```
an array cannot be initialized with a parenthesized initializer
```

What I do wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A C-style array is not assignable, so it cannot be used as the value type of a vector.

If you are using at least C++11, you can `#include <array>` and use `std::array`. (Historically available in Visual C++ 2008 SP1 as `std::tr1::array`).

```
#include <iostream>
#include <array>
#include <vector>
#include <cstring>


int main()
{
    std::vector< std::array<char, 256>> readers;

    std::array<char,256> d;
    strcpy(d.data(), "AAA");
    readers.push_back(d);

}
```

Comment: I'd consider a less direct translation too: `std::vector<std::string>`

Answer (score 0):

You could use `std::array` instead of the antiquated *raw arrays*.

Like this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <array>
#include <vector>
#include <cstring>


int main( )
{
    std::vector< std::array<char, 256> > readers;

    std::array<char, 256> d { "AAA" };
    // strcpy( d.data( ), "AAA" ); not required
    readers.push_back( d );

    std::cout << readers[0].data( ) << '\n';
}
```